# how to open an xml file with any app on android?

Tags: android, xml

I have installed securid app and received an xml file to import. in  the app there is no import utility. you should open the xml file with the app. the xml is an attachment in mail. click on file gives options : open with - but only chrome and html viewer can be selected and no other app can be specified.  on android you can not make a fileassociation by extension. any idea how to open this file with the specific app ?
thanks for all hints
best regards, Guy

Comment: Every editor app should be able to open the file. And your app too. Why dont you open it yourself?

Comment: it is an authentication app and the xml keeps the credentials for this user

Comment: Ok. So why not open it and read it?